# Filter out Items in product collection with find in set

Tags: collection, filter, product-collection, collection-filtering

My product has an attribute **conditions** which contains nothing, one value or a set of values seperated by an comma

### product examples:

```
Product A: condition = ''
Product B: condition = '1'
Product C: condition = '1,2,3'
Product D: condition = '2'
```

### Example queries

If i want to get all products which contain value **1** in field **conditions** i can do something like this:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToSelect('conditions')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('conditions', array('finset' => '1'));
```

This will return product **B** and **C**

If i want to get all products which contain value **1 or 2** in field **conditions** i can do something like this:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToSelect('conditions')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('conditions', array(array('finset' => '1'), array('finset' => '2')));
```

This will return **B**, **C**, and **D**

### Question:

How can i filter out a Product which contains value **3** to only get Product **B** and **D** the magento way?

This means how to add *another* filter which does:

show only products where **find in set** returns **0** for value **3** in field **conditions**

Comment: if you filter product for value 3, how will you get product **B** and **D** ,?

Comment: The question is how to add **another filter** to filter out products which have value 3 in the set of conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope i got your problem right.

```
$productCollection->Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=> 'conditions','finset' => array('1')),
        array('attribute'=> 'conditions','finset' => array('2')),
        array('attribute'=> 'conditions','finset' => array('3')),
    )
);
```